# How to get record value from LinqDataSource via Code Behind

Tags: linq, code-behind, linqdatasource

I've got a LinqDataSource that retrieves a single record.

```
Protected Sub LinqDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles LinqDataSource1.Selecting
    Dim BizForSaleDC As New DAL.BizForSaleDataContext
    e.Result = BizForSaleDC.bt_BizForSale_GetByID(e.WhereParameters("ID")).FirstOrDefault
End Sub
```

I'd like to be able to retrieve the values of said DataSource using the Page_Load function.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Get the right usercontrol'
    Dim ctrl As UserControl
    Select Case DataBinder.Eval(LINQDATASOURCE_SOMETHING.DataItem, "AdType")
        Case 1 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 2 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 3 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case 4 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case Else : ctrl = Nothing
    End Select

    'set the control to visible'
    ctrl.Visible = True
End Sub
```

But obviously the code above doesn't work... I'm just wondering if there's a way to make it work.

Here is the full markup

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server">
        <WhereParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" Name="ID" QueryStringField="ID"
                Type="Int32" />
        </WhereParameters>
    </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <uc:Default ID="Default1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    <uc:ValuPro ID="ValuPro1" runat="server" Visible="false" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what happens is the appropriate usercontrol is enabled and that usercontrol inherits the LinqDataSource and displays the appropriate information.

**EDIT:** It's working now with the code below, however, since I'm really not into hitting the database multiple times for the same info, I'd prefer to get the value from the DataSource.

```
'Query the database'
Dim _ID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString("ID"))
Dim BizForSaleDC As New BizForSaleDataContext
Dim results = BizForSaleDC.bt_BizForSale_GetByID(_ID).FirstOrDefault

'Get the right usercontrol'
Dim ctrl As UserControl
Select Case results.AdType
    Case 1 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
    Case 2 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
    Case 3 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
    Case 4 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
    Case Else : ctrl = Nothing
End Select
```

**EDIT 2:** This appears to be a work around, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way

```
Private AdType As String
Private isSold As Boolean

Protected Sub LinqDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles LinqDataSource1.Selecting
    Dim BizForSaleDC As New DAL.BizForSaleDataContext
    e.Result = BizForSaleDC.bt_BizForSale_GetByID(e.WhereParameters("ID")).FirstOrDefault

    AdType = e.Result.AdType
    isSold = e.Result.isSold
End Sub


Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    'Get the right usercontrol'
    Dim ctrl As UserControl
    Select Case AdType
        Case 1 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 2 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 3 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case 4 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case Else : ctrl = Nothing
    End Select

    ctrl.Visible = True
    'Display SOLD if item is sold'
    ctrl.FindControl("SoldDiv").Visible = isSold

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure if there's a better answer out there, but since no one answered, I figured this as a work around and it seems to work, though it's not as pretty as I thought it should be.

```
Private AdType As String ''# a property to store the Ad Type'
Private isSold As Boolean ''# a property to store whether or not the Ad is sold'

''# when the linq datasource is activated, it pulls the data out of the db'
''# and sets the two properties'
Protected Sub LinqDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs) Handles LinqDataSource1.Selecting
    Dim BizForSaleDC As New DAL.BizForSaleDataContext
    e.Result = BizForSaleDC.bt_BizForSale_GetByID(e.WhereParameters("ID")).FirstOrDefault

    AdType = e.Result.AdType
    isSold = e.Result.isSold
End Sub

''# when the page loads, the properties are already set'
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    ''# Get the right usercontrol'
    Dim ctrl As UserControl
    Select Case AdType ''# using the AdType property from above to decide which UserControl to enable'
        Case 1 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 2 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("Default1"), UserControl)
        Case 3 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case 4 : ctrl = DirectCast(Me.FindControl("ValuPro1"), UserControl)
        Case Else : ctrl = Nothing
    End Select

    ctrl.Visible = True
    ''# Display SOLD if item is sold'
    ctrl.FindControl("SoldDiv").Visible = isSold ''# using the isSold property from above to display the "SOLD" overlay'

End Sub
```